# AutoComplete without a WebService?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying autocomplete option with textbox with multiple values with comma separated but it throws "error" in alert box jquery.

```
<asp:Content ID="content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdminHead">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $('#<%=txtauthor.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Author/Add.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'username':'" + extractLast(request.term) + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            },
            focus: function () {
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var terms = split(this.value);
                terms.pop();
                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                terms.push("");
                this.value = terms.join(", ");
                return false;
            }
        });
        $('#<%=txtauthor.ClientID%>').bind("keydown", function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active)
            {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        function split(val) {
            return val.split(/,\s*/);
        }
        function extractLast(term) {
            return split(term).pop();
        }
    }
</script>
```

And textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtauthor" Width="700px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

and the C# to get the list

```
 [WebMethod]
public static List<AuthorDetail> GetAutoCompleteData(string username)
{
    AuthorCalls mcr = new AuthorCalls ();
    return mcr.GetAutoCompleteAuthorName(username);
}
```

I tried to set breakpoint on method to see but it doesn't invoke that method too.
What am i missing?

Comment: Try to alert the result in the errors section instead of alert("Error");

Comment: I tired but i get [object XMLHttpRequest] error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the URL you provide to for the AJAX call, it assumes that where the specific script gets rendered is in the same relative path (i.e. folder) as the page you are trying to access. In other words, let's assume your page is under `/applicationPath/search.aspx`. It would then assume the URL you are accessing is located under `/applicationPath/Author/Add.aspx` Is that correct?

Alternatively, you can interrogate the network traffic from your browser through it's native DEV tools to see what the error is. A 404 status would mean the URL could not be accessed / found (which I suspect might be the case). Alternatively, a 500 status would mean an exception somewhere in your code, which I think is not likely, seeing as you can't even hit a breakpoint in the code.

Comment: Ok. Now the url look like "/Author/Add.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData" but i checked in chrome and it says 500 (internal server error) and in alert i get [object XMLHttpRequest]

Comment: The 500 status code means there's an error in your code somewhere. So try and debug your code by attaching a debugger and see where it fails...

Comment: Ok. I changed the api url and object XMLHttpReuest error went but i get now 'object Object' error. and in console i see 500 error with- send jquery.js:9597
b.extend.ajax jquery.js:9597
SearchText.$.autocomplete.source Admin:20
t.widget._search jquery-ui.min.js:8
(anonymous function) jquery-ui.min.js:5
t.widget.search jquery-ui.min.js:8
(anonymous function) jquery-ui.min.js:5
(anonymous function) jquery-ui.min.js:8
i

Comment: "[object Object]" is not necessarily an error. Try logging the object in Chrome so you can inspect each individual property of the object. The fact that you're still getting a 500 status code still means you're having trouble in your back-end code. Try debugging your code to see what's going on.